# как получить число простых чисел от каждого элемента в массиве C++?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

мой код дает все простие числа массива но мне нужно найти количество простых чисел каждого отдельно взятого елемента масива...

Примеры:

Входные данные

5 --» 1 2 3 4 5

Результат работы

0 0 1 2 2

Входные данные

11 --» 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31

Результат работы

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

````
 ```
      #include <iostream>

      int main() 
     {
       int n;
       std::cin >> n;
       int arr[100];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
       std::cin >> arr[i];
       }
       std::cout << "N of primes:";
       for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
       {
       for (int j = 2; j <= arr[i] / 2; j++)
       {
        if (arr[i] % j == 0 && arr[i] != j)
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
            break;
           }
        }
        if (arr[i] != 0)
        {
           std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
         }
        }   
       }
      ```
````

я начинающий в C++ поэтому мне нужны простые решение задачи

спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил в код комментарии, чтобы было понятнее.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    // заведем переменную, в которой будем хранить кол-во простых чисел
    long long counter = 0;
    long long n; std::cin >> n;
    // считаем количество вводимых чисел
    for(long long i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        // будем считывать N простых чисел и проверять их на простоту. Переменна flag нужна как переключатель - простое число или нет
        bool flag = true;
        long long tmp; std::cin >> tmp;
        // выведем счетчик
        std::cout << counter << " ";
        // проверка на простоту
        if(tmp == 1) continue; // 1 - не простое число, уходим на новую итерацию
        for(long long d = 2; d * d <= tmp; d++){
            if(tmp % d == 0) flag = false; // если число не простое, не будем увеличиваь счетчик
        }
        if(flag) counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!!!

Comment: а можно решить задачу написав все в int main()  и по простыми способами???

Comment: Тут хранение  в векторе лишняя операция  и  is_prime написана плохо(не эффективно)

Comment: мне нужно написать этот код без #include <vector> и без остальных других функций

Comment: @ARHovsepyan почему сложность O(sqrt(N)) - плохая? Это стандартный способ проверки на простоту. С хранением в векторе согласен, можно было обойтись и без него.

Comment: Nosorog, 1. если проверите число  на нечетность,  тогда  цикл сократится в два раза, а еще лучше проверять во время компиляции.... 2.  Хотите знать больше, не утверждайте, а спросите как. 3. Нет никаких стандартных способов, есть только стандартные правила и инструменты.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan стандартный в плане олимпиданого программирования. Я знаю, что существует алгоритм за log(N), но судя по вопросу и уровню сложности задачи, тут он не требуется. С проверкой на нечетность согласен, постоянно забываю про нее =)  Спасибо, что напомнили. Не совсем понятно, каким образом можно организовать проверку во время компиляции, никогда с таким не сталкивался. Можете подсказать?

Answer (score 0):

````
    ```
      #include <iostream>

       int main() {
       unsigned int n, count = 0, num;
       std::cin >> n;
       int arr[100];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       std::cin >> arr[i];
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       std::cout << count << " ";

       num = arr[i];
       if (num == 2)
       count++;
       if (num < 2 || num % 2 == 0)
       continue;
       int j;
       for (j = 2; j < num; j++)
       if (num % j == 0)
       break;
       if (j * j > num)
       count++;
       }
       }
     ```
````

как решить проблему когда вводятся 10 чисел например --» 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31
Правильный ответ был 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

сейчас программа дает ответ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9